# How to create a reusable component based on a MUI component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

My approach so far:

```
import React from "react";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import {Button, ButtonProps} from "@mui/material";

type Props = { label?: string } & ButtonProps;

export const NavBackButton = ({label = "back", ...rest}: Props) => {
    const history = useHistory();

    return (
        <Button variant="outlined"
                onClick={history.goBack}
                {...rest}>
            {label}
        </Button>
    );
};
```

But this leads to a ts-error for `{...rest}`:

> Type ...Pick<{label?: string} & {children?: React.ReactNode, classes?:
> Partial, color?: OverridableStringUnion<"inherit" |
> "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning",
> ButtonPropsColorOverrides>, disabled?: boolean, disableElevation?:
> boolean, disableFocusRipple?: boolean, endIcon?: React.ReactNode,
> fullWidth?: boolean, href?: string, size?:
> OverridableStringUnion<"small" | "medium" | "large",
> ButtonPropsSizeOverrides>, startIcon?: React.ReactNode, ...} &
> Omit<{action?: React.Ref, centerRipple?: boolean,
> children?: React.ReactNode, classes?: Partial,
> disabled?: boolean, disableRipple?: boolean, disableTouchRipple?:
> boolean, focusRipple?: boolean, focusVisibleClassName?: string,
> LinkComponent?: React.ElementType, onFocusVisible?:
> React.FocusEventHandler, ...}, "classes"> & CommonProps &
> DistributiveOmit<PropsWithoutRef<...<...> & ...<...>> & {ref?:
> Exclude<... | (...) | ... | ..., string> | undefined}, "children" |
> "classes" | "color" | "disabled" | "disableElevation" |
> "disableFocusRipple" | "endIcon" | "fullWidth" | "href" | "size" |
> "startIcon" | ...>, "children" | "classes" | "color" | "disabled" |
> "disableElevation" | "disableFocusRipple" | "endIcon" | "fullWidth" |
> "href" | "size" | "startIcon" | ...> is not assignable to type
> React.ReactNode

Comment: Hi, your code works fine. please see https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-star-qf6f6d?file=/src/App.tsx.

Comment: ty, turned out react-scripts is incompatible with ts v5 which lead to this error, downgraded to ts v4 and now it works

Answer (score 0):

You are destructuring the `rest` object in the props and then trying to destructure `rest` again inside the MUI Button props. Try this:

```
import React from "react";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import {Button, ButtonProps} from "@mui/material";

type Props = { label?: string } & ButtonProps;

export const NavBackButton = ({label = "back", rest}: Props) => {
    const history = useHistory();

    return (
        <Button variant="outlined"
                onClick={history.goBack}
                {...rest}>
            {label}
        </Button>
    );
};
```